# Multiple data sets, input into separate workbook, output each dataset into own field

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new, never done programming before and never used a forum before. I have read a lot of other posts to get as far as I have done in Excel to try and get it to perform as I require.

Basically I have a number of data sets, each with 4 variables, each set needs to be copied into appropriate fields on another worksheet, then the 2 outputs from this, recorded back onto the first sheet in 2 separate columns for each data set.
I have got the macro to do nearly all of it however it pastes only the last set of data outputs in the cells not each individual set.

Unfortunately I appear not to be able to add screen shots.
Currently my macro text is:

```
Sub macro1()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("C2:C6")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    rCell.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste

    Next rCell

    Dim rCell2 As Range
    Dim rRng2 As Range

    Set rRng2 = Sheet1.Range("D2:D6")

    For Each rCell2 In rRng2.Cells
    rCell2.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste
    Range("C8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("J2:J6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Next rCell2

    Dim rCell3 As Range
    Dim rRng3 As Range

    Set rRng3 = Sheet1.Range("E2:E6")

    For Each rCell3 In rRng3.Cells
    rCell3.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste

    Next rCell3

    Dim rCell4 As Range
    Dim rRng4 As Range

    Set rRng4 = Sheet1.Range("F2:F6")

    For Each rCell4 In rRng4.Cells
    rCell4.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste
    Range("D8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("K2:K6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Next rCell4

End Sub
```

Apologies for the repetition, I hope someone can help.

Also if there are any good books that people can rate to learn basic macro and programming language that would be great.

[image: 1]
  [image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Range` variables which is good but you are then using `Select` which should be avoided.

If you want to copy from `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C6")` and paste into `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C6")`, you can do this in one line of code. You do not need to loop through the cells for this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C6").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2")
```

Your code as posted was looping through the cells but was always pasting into the same cell.

You can copy a larger block of code and it looks like your code is trying to copy cells C2:F6. Normally you can do that with one line:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:F6").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2")
```

But maybe the paste special causes the values in columns D & E to get changed?

The `PasteSpecial` method requires two lines of code but this seems ok in your code. These lines of code copies one value and pastes it into five cells:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C8").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:J6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

You can simplify your code to:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C6").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D6").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D2")

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C8").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:J6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E6").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F6").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F2")

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D8").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K2:K6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

And maybe copy larger blocks of cells to reduce the number of copy operations?

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:D6").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2")

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C8").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:J6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:F6").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2")

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D8").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K2:K6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```